# Pandas: Filter dataframe with data from another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with two fields, *user* and *data*, and a series *threshold* indexed by users. I would like to filter my dataframe to only keep the rows that correspond to values of the field *data* less than the *threshold* for that *user*. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would encourage others to answer your question if you demonstrated an effort in solving the problem. Also, could you please ensure your code is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: can you add a sample from your input data?

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `loc`:

> Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array

you can find more info about loc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

---

**for example:**

```
df

   user  data
0     1    50
1     2    60
2     3    70
3     4    80
4     5    80
5     6    90
6     7    50
7     8    60
8     9    55
9    10    89


trsh

   threshold
0         54
1         52
2         53
3         57
4         81
5         82
6         61
7         57
8         75
9         65

df.loc[df.data >= trsh.threshold]

   user  data
1     2    60
2     3    70
3     4    80
5     6    90
7     8    60
9    10    89
```